# How to fire a trigger after data has been inserted in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to fire a trigger after my table has been filled with records ,I don't want to fire a row-wise trigger.

Please tell how can we do that in mysql?

Comment: Can you put the comment also in the question (and fix formatting/spelling)? I believe it'll help you get attention and good answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON table_name
```

***Updated:***

The FOR EACH ROW option determines whether the trigger is a row trigger or a statement trigger. If you specify FOR EACH ROW, then the trigger fires once for each row of the table that is affected by the triggering statement. The absence of the FOR EACH ROW option indicates that the trigger fires only once for each applicable statement, but not separately for each row affected by the statement.

Comment: Thanks Masi,but my prolem is that i want to fire trigger after inserting the whole data.eg if i have 100 rows i want to insert the 100 rows in a table then fire a trigger ,i dont want to fire a trigger after each row.

Comment: @bhard, yah its for that only. to fire a trigger after every row you should add "For each row" in above query.